# Tricky Combinatoric Question, regarding a Matrix

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, discrete-mathematics

We randomly choose (with repetition) $2n^2$ numbers from the set {$1,2,...,k$}.

Than, we randomly arrange the $2n^2$ chosen numbers in a $n$ x $2n$ matrix.

How much different matrices exists?

---

My attempt:

We choose $2n^2$ numbers from $k$ numbers with no order matter, and with repetition: $\binom{2n^2+k-1}{2n^2}$.

Then, every cell in the matrix choose a number from the $a=\binom{2n^2+k-1}{2n^2}$ numbers we randomly chose earlier, with order matter, and with no repetition, so we have $\frac{a!}{(a-2n^2)!}$ options.

Is that correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but why isn't the answer $k^{2n^2}$? Each of the $2n^2$ entries can be any of the numbers $1, \ldots, k$.

Comment: @angryavian we first choose a set to start with, for example if $k=3$, and $n=2$, than we choose $8$ numbers from the set {$1,2,3$}. For example we might get {$1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3$}, and then, we randomly arrange those numbers in the matrix. So if we have $1$ in cell one, and another $1$ in cell two, we must not count it twice, like they are different $1$s.

Comment: If your goal is to count the number of possible matrices that can arise from this procedure, then the intermediate step is irrelevant since all $k^{2n^2}$ matrices are possible. If your goal is rather to count the number of possible matrices that can arise from a *specific* initial choice of $2n^2$ numbers, then your answer will depend on this initial set of $2n^2$ numbers.

Comment: @angryavian The question ask for the specific group of the chosen $2n^2$ numbers..